# Why when I try to access array of structures it returns random values? (C)

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct, return

I have a function that returns pointer to array of structures. However, when I try to access any of the values of returned structure, it prints random symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MY {
   int i;
   char string[30];
};

struct MY* myFunc() {
  struct MY arrayOfStructs[3];
  struct MY tempStruct;
  struct MY* arrayOfStructsPtr = arrayOfStructs;

  tempStruct.i = 1;
  tempStruct.string[0] = 'H';
  tempStruct.string[1] = 'i';
  arrayOfStructs[0] = tempStruct;

  tempStruct.i = 2;
  tempStruct.string[0] = 'L';
  tempStruct.string[1] = 'o';
  arrayOfStructs[1] = tempStruct;

  tempStruct.i = 3;
  tempStruct.string[0] = 'M';
  tempStruct.string[1] = 'Y';
  arrayOfStructs[2] = tempStruct;

  return arrayOfStructsPtr;
}

int main()
{
   struct MY* arrayOfStructs = myFunc();
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%d\n", arrayOfStructs[i].i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array you are pointing to no longer exists when `myFunc` returns, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Than how can I return an array?

Comment: It either needs to have static storage duration or you can allocate memory using `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: Apart from what has already been commented: `struct MY* arrayOfStructs = myFunc();` is conceptually wrong, because after that you wouldn't know to how many structs `arrayOfStructs` points, `arrayOfStructs` is not an array but merely a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a reference to the local array which stops to exist when function returns. It is Undefined Behaviour.

You need:

```
struct MY* myFunc(void) {
  static struct MY arrayOfStructs[3];
```

or

```
struct MY* myFunc(void) {
  struct MY *arrayOfStructs = malloc(3 * sizeof(*arrayOfStructs));
```

or pass the buffer allocated by the caller.

```
struct MY *myFunc(struct MY *arrayOfStructs) {
   /* .... */
```

If you dynamically allocate memory you should `free` it after use

Comment: You should mention the corresponding free in main()[

Comment: @AllanWind does it have to be called from the `main`?

Comment: @0___________ In this case, yes, but in general caller usually free memory.

Answer (score 1):

You return a pointer to a local variable which is out of scope when the function returns.  Some alternatives:

1. The caller `main()` allocates variable and pass it to `myFunc()` for initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

struct MY {
    int i;
    char string[30];
};

void myFunc(struct MY arrayOfStructs[N]) {
    char *strings[N] = { "Hi", "Lo", "MY" };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arrayOfStructs[i].i = i + 1;
        strcpy(arrayOfStructs[i].string, strings[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct MY arrayOfStructs[N];
    myFunc(arrayOfStructs);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arrayOfStructs[i].i);
}
```

As used here you don't really need to store `i` as it's just index of the struct + 1.

2. `myFunc()` dynamically allocate the variables with `malloc()` and return the pointer.  Caller is responsible for free'ing the allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

struct MY {
    int i;
    char string[30];
};

struct MY *myFunc() {
    struct MY *arrayOfStructs = malloc(N * sizeof *arrayOfStructs);
    if(!arrayOfStructs) return NULL; // malloc failed
    char *strings[N] = { "Hi", "Lo", "MY" };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof strings / sizeof *strings; i++) {
        arrayOfStructs[i].i = i + 1;
        strcpy(arrayOfStructs[i].string, strings[i]);
    }
    return arrayOfStructs;
}

int main() {
    struct MY *arrayOfStructs = myFunc();
    if(!arrayOfStructs) return 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arrayOfStructs[i].i);
    free(arrayOfStructs);
}
```

3. `myFunc()`: make variables static (not recommended).

Comment: void myFunc(struct MY arrayOfStructs[3]) it is confusing for beginners as they think that you pass the array, not the reference. I would avoid at this OP level

Comment: @0___________ It doesn't matter in this case if op understands that arrays degrade to a pointer.  Caller allocated variables is great technique when it's possible.

Comment: I meant the form of the parameter not the general idea